# SSRS Grouping merge details

Tags: reporting-services

Here is my table

```
EmployeeNr  IDNumber        Period      MonthlyIncome   IncentiveAmount
0000002     8912135105086   2017-04-30  3975.00         1000.00
0000002     8912135105086   2017-05-31  4658.38         670.31
0000002     8912135105086   2017-06-30  5292.19         353.90
0000003     4912015215108   2017-05-31  4274.38         862.81
0000003     4912015215108   2017-06-30  5503.75         248.13
```

Here is how i am able to display it with grouping:

[image: Image of Report]

So my question is can i display it with grouping so that the different values for each employee is only in one row? 
I know how to get to the result with creating a table on my query select with all the months and looping trough to ad the values but I would like to avoid that if possible

EDIT
Here is how i want it to display:

[image: Result Desired]

The test come from

```
=IIf(Month(Fields!Period.Value) = ((Month(First(Fields!StartDate.Value, 
"PayrollTaxYear")) + 0 - 1) Mod 12) + 1, Fields!MonthlyIncome.Value, "test")
```

I use this statement to display the data under the month it is in according to the payroll year start and end, That is also why it start on this example from march.

Edit 2

First One

[image: First One]

Second One

[image: Second One]

Comment: What is your desired output here?  Could you add a mock-up to your question?  Depending on how you want this to look will determine if it is possible or not.  Also, where are those `test` values coming from?  They are not included in your table data provided.

Comment: Thanks for the desired output.  Could you add your report design?  This should be fairly simple with row and column grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use column grouping in your report, which has the same effect of using a `pivot`:

[image]

The expression for the month name headings is just `=MonthName(Month(Fields!Period.Value))`

Which outputs:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, never saw anyone use Column grouping before so learned a lot.